# Python decompiler uncompyle6 unknown variable name characters

Tags: python, batch-file, decompiler

Im working on creating a mod for a game, and part of the process for doing this is to decompile the games source python code. Using a bat file the games community has created, the decompilation has no issues.

However when using the same decompiler process on other mods in order to learn how other modders create their mods i get a weird issue when the decompiler processes variable names on specific mods.

The variable names will be in a different language and with char codes windows does not understand (ie a box), however the rest of the code remains in English.
I further tested this by decompiling multiple versions of the same mod and each time the variable names change but the rest of the code remains the same, which leads me to believe the creator of the mod is not changing their variable names but the decompiler is getting something wrong.
Also when i take the variable names through a translator it is absolute nonsense.

This is the line of code used to actually decompile the source python code:

```
@for /R %TD% %%f in (*.pyc) do (uncompyle6 --asm --grammar --tree -o "%%~df%%~pf%%~nf.py" "%%~df%%~pf%%~nf.pyc")
```

Version info:

```
# uncompyle6 version 3.3.4
# Python bytecode 3.7 (3394)
# Decompiled from: Python 3.7.0b5 (v3.7.0b5:abb8802389, May 31 2018, 01:54:01) [MSC v.1913 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

How can I verify that this is a decompiler issue and not the source code.

The only other possibility I can see is that this particular mod im having the issue with is being obfuscated by the author, but i do not know enough about python to know if thats something that you can do or not. Also that the rest of the code looks formatted and very readable, its only the variable names.

Decompiling the source code for the game is accepted by the authors of the game and the community, as its necessary to mod the game.
However I have not seen anything against decompiling other modders code, especially since im doing this only to learn and understand, and NOT to steal/plagiarize other peoples work.

Update:

I have also tried using windows 10, and forcing utf 8 encoding on the command line.
Also I am getting the same effect on other decompiler scripts.
which leads me to believe the source code might be obfuscated.

Comment: Not all programmers are native English speakers. Variable names are really the only thing that they can use their native language with (libraries are usually english and keywords in python are all english). Make sure whatever console you're using is set up for unicode.

Comment: I advise you yo use `"%%~dpnf.py" "%%~dpnf.pyc"` not `"%%~df%%~pf%%~nf.py" "%%~df%%~pf%%~nf.pyc"`.

Comment: @Aaron Im attempting to set the command line to use utf 8 with "chcp 65001" but it appears Im stilling getting the weird variable names

Comment: Im going to try this on a windows 10 computer, from what im reading win 10 has better unicode support in cmd line.

Comment: @Compo Im afraid i dont understand the difference between those. I did make the change but it does not have any effect on the issue.

Comment: Are you sure that the weird characters are in a variable _name_? I could bet that such a characters are part of the creation date/time of the compiled file!

Comment: @Aacini I can guarantee you its a variable name.

Comment: @DirtyRedz, I provided advice, the difference is `16` less characters and therefore less chance of typo's and misreads. Also does `-o` not expect an output directory path? Either `.`, _(current directory)_ or `%%~dp`, _(adjacent to the `.pyc` file)_, should help. e.g. `@For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Where /R "%TD%" *.pyc 2^>NUL')Do @uncompyle6 --asm --grammar --tree -o . "%%A" "%%~nA.py"` or `@For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Where /R "%TD%" *.pyc 2^>NUL')Do @uncompyle6 --asm --grammar --tree -o "%%~dpA" "%%A" "%%~nA.py"`. _The last quoted string may not be required as it could be the default file name._